# Check if first event is occurred but second didn't

Tags: jquery

I have a code, that if I mousenter to li element, it's height will be increased, and other two lis height will be decreased.

```
$("li").mouseover(function(){   

var thisName    =   $(this).attr("name"),
    lis         =   [];

    lis[0]      =   $("li[name=first]");
    lis[1]      =   $("li[name=second]");
    lis[2]      =   $("li[name=third]");

$(this).animate({
    height: "200px"
}); 

for(i=0; i<lis.length; i++) {
    if(lis[i].attr("name")!=thisName) {
        lis[i].animate({
            height: "50px"
        });
    };
};  
});
```

I also have code for mouseleave. That will return those three li's height to 100px.

When I mouseleave, not into another li element, everything works ok.

But I have a problem if I mouseleave from li element, and mousenter to another. Then:
First mouseleave event will work, and resise every li to 100px, then mouseenter event will work.

This looks prety bad. I would like to cancel all other animations when mousenter or mouse leave event occur.

Comment: And where's the code for this, all you've posted is something for `mouseover`, nothing for `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` ?

Comment: Maybe you could provide a jsfiddle which replicates your issue

Comment: The first answer is perfect :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .stop(true) to stop the animation

```
$("li").mouseover(function () {

    var thisName = $(this).attr("name"),
        lis = [];

    lis[0] = $("li[name=first]");
    lis[1] = $("li[name=second]");
    lis[2] = $("li[name=third]");

    //use .stop(true)
    $(this).stop(true).animate({
        height: "200px"
    });

    for (i = 0; i < lis.length; i++) {
        if (lis[i].attr("name") != thisName) {
            lis[i].stop(true).animate({
                height: "50px"
            });
        };
    };
});
```

---

And your code can be cleaned up like

```
var $lis = $("li").mouseover(function () {
    //use .stop(true)
    $(this).stop(true).animate({
        height: "200px"
    });
    $lis.not(this).stop(true).animate({
        height: "50px"
    });
});
```

---

Also you can use .hover() to register both mouseenter and mouseleave handlers like

```
var $lis = $("li").hover(function () {
    //use .stop(true)
    $(this).stop(true).animate({
        height: "200px"
    });
    $lis.not(this).stop(true).animate({
        height: "50px"
    });
}, function () {
    $lis.stop(true).animate({
        height: "100px"
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gbUxv/)

Comment: Hmm could you please build it up, that it will affect only li elements, that have names: "first", "second", "third"? Because now $lis = $("li") is selecting all li elements.

Comment: @user3021198 change `var $lis = $("li").hover(function () {` to `var $lis = $("li[name]").hover(function () {`

Comment: $("li[name=first],li[name=second],li[name=third]").hover(function ()
Ok thanx. That works. :)